# Float a DIV after scrolling accross the DIV

Tags: css, html, css-float

This is the URL: [Check this URL](http://classictutorials.com)

In that there is a red ribbon with subscribe, like etc.

Its fixed on the top. All i want is the ribbon should start floating on the top of the page as soon as some one scrolls below it..again if he scrolls up the ribbon goes and sits in its place.

Basic idea is that ribbon should be visible to the user always.

How to acheive something like this in CSS?

Comment: did you try position: fixed instead of absolute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop()>$('#socio').position().top){
    $('#socio').css({position:'fixed',top:0});
  }else{
    $('#socio').css({position:'relative'});
  } 

});
```

something like this should work

Comment: What was the small fix?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Chris Coyier's "Persistent Header":
http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

> This is some code to get the header of some content area to stay visible at the top of the screen as you scroll through that content. Then go away when you've scrolled past that relevant section.

He also posts a link to [another](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/) implementation.